# sftp with batch mode suppresses mput and mget command response echo

Tags: shell-script, openssh, sftp, batch-jobs

I recently upgraded OpenSSH from 6.0 to 7.5.

My code captures the `put`/`get` command response echo and processes it for verification.

Code:

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2
  exec > $TempSessionLog 2>&1
  set -x 
  cd $LocalDir
  sftp -o PreferredAuthentications=hostbased,publickey -P $rport -b $batfile "$ruser"@"$ripaddress" > $TempLogFile  << EndFTP  
EndFTP
  retval="$?"  
    exec 1>&3 2>&4
  set +x
```

In OpenSSH 6.0, the response is captured in `TempLogFile` as

```
sftp> cd /user/data/errors/support/01
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /user/data/errors/support/01
sftp> mput "EVERYTHING_GAA_20131029_113243_R9976594.txt.D20131029.T1520.txt"
**Uploading EVERYTHING_GAA_20131029_113243_R9976594.txt.D20131029.T1520.txt to /user/data/errors/support/01/EVERYTHING_GAA_20131029_113243_R9976594.txt.D20131029.T1520.txt**
sftp> bye
```

After upgrading to OpenSSH 7.5, the echo has stopped

```
sftp> cd /user/data/errors/support/01
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /user/data/errors/support/01
sftp> mput "EVERYTHING_GAA_20131029_113243_R9976594.txt.D20131029.T1520.txt"
sftp> bye
```

Any idea how to get the response echoes back?

Comment: Can you use `scp` instead of `sftp`? For example, `scp -p EVERYTHING_GAA_20131029_113243_R9976594.txt.D20131029.T1520.txt "$ruser@$ripaddress":/user/data/errors/support/01/`

Comment: Are you sure there is not define the -q option somewhere ?

Comment: @Roaima - scp unfortunately is not an option with the current requirements.

Comment: As your script is basically doing a single command anyway, and you check the result using an output, you can do without the batch mode. Just pass the commands using a standard input.

Answer (score 1):

Since OpenSSH 6.3 ([commit](https://anongit.mindrot.org/openssh.git/commit/sftp.c?id=9303e6527bb5ca7630c765f28624702c212bfd6c)), the `-b` implies `-q` and the `-q` is really quite:

> make "sftp -q" do what it says on the sticker: hush everything but errors;

```c
case 'b':
    // ...
    showprogress = 0;
    quiet = batchmode = 1;
```

```c
if (!quiet)
    printf("Uploading %s to %s\n", g.gl_pathv[i], abs_dst);
```

---

There's no way to revert the behavior.

---

But if your script is basically doing a single command anyway, and you check the result using an output, you can do without the batch mode. Just pass the commands using a standard input.

Comment: i used the single command for testing. basically the number of transfers vary from job to job.

Comment: OK, but then you can still do without a batch mode.